# Selenium - How to identify li item based on value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the following list in a webpage that I am trying to scrape:

```
<div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="height: 54px; width: 100%;">
<ul class="rcbList">
<li class="rcbItem">Jules Salles-Wagner (FRENCH, 1814–1898)</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Peter Nadin (BRITISH, 1954)</li>
<li class="rcbItem">Uri Aran (ISRAELI, 1977)</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to select the item that contains the text **Uri Aran**. How can I do that through Selenium? There are other lists with different class name in the same website as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//li[@class='rcbItem' and contains(text(),'Uri Aran')]").click()
```

You'd want to get the one that contains the text of Uri Aran.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text ***Uri Aran*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `nth-child()`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rcbScroll.rcbWidth > ul.rcbList li:nth-child(3)")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `nth-of-type()`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rcbScroll.rcbWidth > ul.rcbList li:nth-of-type(3)")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `last-child`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rcbScroll.rcbWidth > ul.rcbList li:last-child")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `last-of-type`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rcbScroll.rcbWidth > ul.rcbList li:last-of-type")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *index*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rcbScroll rcbWidth']/ul[@class='rcbList']//following::li[3]")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `last()`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rcbScroll rcbWidth']/ul[@class='rcbList']//li[last()]")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *innerText*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[starts-with(., 'Uri Aran')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```